# Best way to use .less files in a large scale application developed using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, less

I am creating a large scale application using AngularJS which is a Single Page App. I kept all the html files under the folder Views like below.

```
Views
    Sample
        sample.html
        sampleheader.html
        samplefooter.html
    Sample1
        sample1.html
        sample1header.html
        sample1footer.html
```

I am going use .less for styling purposes.

Is it advisable to create separate .less file under each views or to create a common .less file for all the screens?

Please advise the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest having a look @ the ng-boilerplate build management system. Its an example starter project for large apps, it separates the .less files per module/feature directory & uses Grunt to automate the concatenation of the individual .less to one main css file.

https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp

Also, have a read here:

https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp/tree/v0.3.1-release/src/less

And heres one feature/module dir with .less

https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp/tree/v0.3.1-release/src/app/home